# Could not submit code to Ideone

Tags: java

When i click submit button nothing happens

My code:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;




class TestClass {

static int cost;
static int m;
static int dp[][];
static int graph[][];
static int vis[][];
static int first[];
static boolean fin;



public static class Batman{

    int to ;
    int from ;
    int d;

    public Batman(int to , int from , int d){
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.d =d;
    }
}

public static int find(int x , int[] p){

    if(p[x]==x) return x;
    return find(p[x], p);
}

public static void union(int x , int y , int[] size , int[] p){

    if(size[x]>size[y]){
        p[y]=x;
        size[x]++;

    }else{
        p[x]=y;
        size[y]++;
    }

}

public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException  {



    InputStream inputStream = System.in;
    InputReader in = new InputReader(inputStream);
//Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int n = in.nextInt();
int[] Parent = new int[n];
int[] Size= new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    Parent[i]=i;
    Size[i]=1;
}
Batman[] trees = new Batman[n-1];
int min =Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int dd=0;
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){ 
    int xx = in.nextInt()-1;
    int yy = in.nextInt()-1;
    int d =in.nextInt();
    trees[i] = new Batman(xx, yy, d);
    if(xx==0 && min>d)
    {
        min = d;
        dd=yy;
    }

    if(yy==0 && min>d){

       min =d;
       dd=xx;
    }
    }


    Arrays.sort(trees, new Comparator<Batman>() {

        public int compare(Batman a, Batman b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return a.d-b.d;
        }
    });
    int ans=0;
    if(min!=Integer.MAX_VALUE){
        ans=min;
    Parent[dd]=0;
    Size[0]+=1;
    }


    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){

        int xx = find(trees[i].from,Parent);
        int yy = find(trees[i].to,Parent);

        if(xx!=yy){
            ans+=trees[i].d;
            union(xx, yy, Size,Parent);

        }
    }

    System.out.println(ans);


}
 }
class InputReader {
    public BufferedReader reader;
    public StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), 32768);
        tokenizer = null;
    }

    public String next() {
        while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            try {
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }
    public long nextLong(){
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

}
```

Sample Input:

```
4
4 3 1
4 2 2
1 2 1
```

Where is the problem ? same thing Happens when i am trying to submit the solution of this [Problem](http://www.codechef.com/CDVA2015/problems/CDVA1507) when i click submit button nothing happens

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Please choose a title that describes the question.

Answer (score 1):

It has to follow the guidelines in the example program:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the correct language selected (e.g. Java or Java7). Also, make sure you correctly enter the input as well:

```
4
4 3 1
4 2 2
1 2 1
```

There should be a next line character after that last line.

Here is [a working version](http://ideone.com/HrdiN5).

Comment: Name of main class doesn't have to be `Ideone`. It works also if copy-paste OP code without changing any name: http://ideone.com/C4Wj2U

Comment: @Pshemo have corrected my code or just you copy and paste it

Comment: @user4447943 it was copy-paste from your question, I didn't edit anything.

Comment: @Pshemo Updated. I thought you had to, but alas I was wrong :/